# Binding generic ObservableCollection to ItemsSource of Listview, kills XAML Designer and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

when my app launches, I'm setting the DataContext of my window as such:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
    <vm:DefaultViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Then I bind an ObservableCollection to a ListView later on with:

```
<ListView Margin="10"
          MinHeight="0"
          BorderThickness="0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Client ID" Width="85" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientId}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Client Name" Width="220" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Branch" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Branch}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Client Number" Width="125" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ClientNumber}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Fed ID" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FedId}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Account Manager" Width="155" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AccountManager}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Region" Width="61" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Region}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

That client list is queried upon startup and set in the default view model's constructor. The problem is that the application now doesn't even launch - but the client list is bound and visible in the XAML Designer! And it brings Visual Studio to a halt in general. What's the issue here?

Edit: here is how the data is being bound (GetClients just runs a query that populates the results into an ObservableCollection) -

```
public class DefaultViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DefaultViewModel()
    {
        _clients = DataSource.GetClients();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Client> _clients;
    public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients
    {
        get { return _clients; }
        set { Set(ref _clients, value); }
    }


    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And here is that GetClients function:

```
        public static ObservableCollection<Client> GetClients()
    {
        var clients = new ObservableCollection<Client>();
        var query = File.ReadAllText(@"file_path");

        using (var cn = new OleDbConnection(pia_connection_string))
        {
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, cn);
            cn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var client = new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString())
                    };
                    clients.Add(client);
                }
            }
        }

        return clients;
    }
```

Comment: Step through the code you added (the code that broke everything) in the debugger and see what happens. Or show us the code. Don't say "Oh, I did something somewhere that I won't show you and it broke; what line number did it break on and why?"

Comment: It happens even before any code actually runs. It's as soon as I add the 'ItemsSource' line that Visual Studio starts to crash - that's why it's so weird.

Comment: I can't help you if you won't show me any code. `Clients` is something; presumably a property. If it is, it's got code in the setter and code in the getter. I don't know what's in either one; maybe it doesn't have both (don't ask me). Maybe you're setting it, maybe you're not; I have no way of knowing. If it's a collection, it's populated, in some way (don't ask me how) with something (I don't know what).

Comment: Ok sorry - just edited my original post with code from the VM. Is that enough?

Comment: DataSource.GetClients(), the problem lies inside that call.

Comment: *"It happens even before any code actually runs"* -- how do I know that's not a wild guess?

Comment: I would bet money that @E-Bat has identified where the problem lies. Put a breakpoint on that call and see what happens.

Comment: Ok - I will step through it

Comment: I think I found the issue - had nothing to do with my GetClients in theory but rather the number of rows returned. I added a MaxHeight to my ListView and that fixed all of the performance issues. Runs perfectly now. I tried removing it and running again and experienced the same issue. Maybe something to do with the control itself?